# requestFullscreen() not working with modifier keys inside keyup event

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, event-handling, html5-fullscreen

I want to toggle fullscreen on an element, but the `requestFullscreen()` function isn't working, despite the fact it is called while responding to user interaction ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen)).
I can't find out why it doesn't work with Modifier Keys ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values#modifier_keys)).

Here's the snippet from my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chris5/j5yha2sm/13/):

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (document.fullscreenElement)
    return document.exitFullscreen()
  document.body.firstElementChild.requestFullscreen();  // Fails on CTRL, SHIFT, ALT ...
});
```

I also don't understand how it ***does*** work if you press a mouse button or any other key press between each toggle with CTRL, SHIFT, or ALT keys. For example, this would work: Left Mouse Click, Shift, Shift, Left Mouse Click, Shift, Shift...

I **need** this to work for my Chrome Extension, so maybe there is a workaround? Thanks.

Comment: @Patrick uh... what? when I do `document.body.onkeydown = ev=>console.log(ev.key)` and press my modifier keys, I get the events picked up for Control, Shift, and Alt on Google Chrome.

Comment: @user is right. The events are there, but fail to trigger the `requestFullscreen`. What's even stranger is my last paragraph in the question explaining how it magically works when pressing any other button and then, separately, a modifier key. Try it on the provided fiddle.

Comment: @NehaSoni It always works when you press a non-modifier key. However, when opening a Fiddle, you have to put focus on the output document in order for it to receive events, but that is not the problem.

Comment: Yeah maybe because in fiddle we have to first focus on the web container to see the results. Can you please explain the problem more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated MDN docs - [Features gated by user activation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/User_activation) - specify exactly what activation triggering input events require. In short, the Esc key and shortcut keys reserved by the user agent (aka modifier keys) don't trigger transient activation. There is no workaround.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your explanation correctly, you mean that when you first interact with the element, for example, click on the element first and then press let's say enter, it works. But when you come for the first time and try to press any key, it does not enter the full screen.

In general, the `keydown` and `keyup` events can be fired without first clicking on an element. That means if you are triggering the full-screen mode on the `keyup` event then it should work without user interaction but it won't. The reason is-

**The `requestFullscreen()` method needs that it is contacted in reaction to a user gesture, such as a click event, touch event, or `keydown` event that was triggered by a user interaction. This is a security feature of the browser to stop websites from taking over the user's screen without their consent.**

**When a user interacts with a webpage by clicking a button, tapping on the screen, or pressing a key, the browser believes that the user has initiated the action and accordingly allows the website to take over the screen using the `requestFullscreen()` method.**

However, if the `requestFullscreen()` method is called from a keyup event that was not triggered by a user interaction, such as a script like a keypress a key press, the browser may not permit the website to take over the screen because it cannot decide whether the action was started by the user or by a script.

This is likely why the `requestFullscreen()` method fails when called from a keyup event that is not initiated by a user motion, such as when using modifier keys like CTRL, SHIFT, or ALT.

Comment: Thanks, MDN updated the docs recently so I'll post the answer.